# Publishing Counts for objects in Meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor, meteor-publications

On my server side I have for various objects a publication which basically returns the count. Every different object has a different publication name like this:

```
Meteor.publish('object1Count', function(...

Meteor.publish('object2Count', function(...
```

Which are something like this:

```
Meteor.publish('object1Count', function(arg) {
var self = this;
var count = 0;
var initializing = true;

var query = arg?{arg:arg}:{};
var projection = !arg?{limit:1}:{};

var handle = Object1.find(query, projection).observeChanges({
  added: function (idx) {
    count++;
    if (!initializing)
      self.changed("totalcounts", 1, {count: count});  
  },
  removed: function (idx) {
    count--;
    self.changed("totalcounts", 1, {count: count});  
  }
});

initializing = false;

self.added("totalcounts", 1, {count: count});

self.ready();

self.onStop(function () {
  handle.stop();
});

});
```

But as you see inside each of these methods there will be this line

```
self.added("totalcounts", 1, {count: count});
```

In fact on the client side when I need to access the count of an Object I do like this:

```
template.subscribe('object1Count', template.reactiveEventId.get());
...
TotalCounts = (typeof TotalCounts==='undefined')?new Mongo.Collection("totalcounts"):TotalCounts;
```

It apparently works, but now that I read it twice I wonder why, the "totalcounts" collection looks like the same for all the objects, so if I switch between pages needing different totalcounts (for different objects), I guess that the client destroys the local collection totalcounts and creates a new one. Does this happen also server side?

So finally my question is: what is the best practice? The projects need the total counts for various reasons: pagination, charts, etc.. I want to create the total counts server side and just pass the minimum data for that. Should I create different "totalcounts" for every object? What's the efficient way of doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

```
self.added("totalcounts", 1, {count: count});
```

it means add to collection name `totalcounts` a document with `_id` is `1` and the rest of data is `{count: count}`.
Because they have the same _id then you can't make more than 1 subscription.
Btw, when the template is "unmounted" it will auto stop subscriptions.

Comment: Ohh I see, so if I try to use two of those collections in the same template I'd find funny data (probably the count would always be the one from the last subscribed subscription, I'll give it a try to see if it's as expected). Anyways, is it correct to created different totalcounts, something like object1totalcount, object2totalcount, etc..? Is there a reference on best practices?

Comment: I think it depends on your system features. But you should use less subscription as possible and use methods to load the data for better performance.